# UML activity diagram for eCommerce site

Tags: diagram, uml, workflow-activity

I'm trying to make an activity diagram for an eCommerce site.  Most of the site has been developed already, but I find the task of making its diagram a tedious one because of the site's complexity. I've started working on it but it would probably take me days to finish it.

Are there any examples of activity diagrams for eCommerce sites out there that could help guide me?

Comment: I don't get the "Most of the site has been developed" part here, please explain. Are you making a design for something that is already built?

Comment: Yes, I am making a design for something that is already built. It serves as an explanation to a client, to see what has been done and what remains to be done.

Comment: I googled ;) http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~matz/instruct/csc407/lectures/uml_for_e-commerce.pdf (as a guide) http://www.utdallas.edu/~chung/George.Suwei/Project48.ppt as a sample...

Comment: I've already found the first of your links. They are both very good findings. You should consider moving them to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anything other than a pretty simple site, I'm not sure building a complete Activity Diagram is a useful investment.

You mention it as a means to show progress to a client.  I've used for similar purposes but tend to split as follows:

1. High level AD that shows the major sections of the site e.g. login/security, education, sales, service.
2. For each major section, the diagram has a bullet list summary of the tasks (stories/Use Cases) the section supports.  e.g. for sales: browse/search stock, add items to basket, checkout.  It also shows the primary nav among site sections (e.g. login ->sales / service, etc.).
3. If necessary, create a separate spreadsheet that lists each task / page and its status.

I've never had the diagram take more than a day to create - usually a few hours.  It seems to work because it provides the high-level overview while the spreadsheet(s) have the detail.  The diagram also tends to be less volatile --> less maintenance.

Depending on your dev process you many not need the spreadsheets (e.g. if using a planning tool such as xplanner etc. you can generate progress reports straight from that).

hth.